# Stackoverflow site looks wierd and outdated. Is my PC infected or what?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

Just a little while ago, when I am browsing stackoverflow, If I go to any question, the site in my PC appears like the image attached.

I have checked this in both chrome and Mozilla, the result is same.

is it normal or my pc has got some Malware, just seeking a confirmation.

[image]

Comment: It's a kind of throwback site. Click on the time travel icon on the top left to revert back to the new site

Comment: @NetEmmanuel - what does that means?

Comment: Stackoverflow is trying to give you a feeling of the old look of the site when they started out

Comment: Short answer : it's not a malware

Comment: Ok I see. thanks for the info. I thought that there is something wrong with my PC.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like April 1 "gift", there's a "Go to the future" button on the bottom left corner

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the top right of this image: it's supposed to be a joke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLw6X.png)

It seems that it's a sort of joke, although I don't understand it. It'll be back to normal probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Press a "Go to the future" button to force your browser to render a usual StackOverflow.

But you might miss vivid colors and a unicorn. In that case, input ...

`javascript:$.cookie("tm2019", null, { path: '/', expires: -1 });`

to an address bar then hit `Enter` to go back and have fun again.

I don't really know how this could happen on this site, but I found this in source code.

[image]